# How do I print a single email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

It is easy to print the complete thread, however how do I print a **single** email message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the email open, click the down arrow for the Action menu on the email you want to print and select print.  It will open that single email in a new window in a printable format.